# How can I grep in a Perl loop?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am trying to `grep` in Perl using the following code:

```
my @S = grep /M1A3B6/, @AR3; 
print @S;
```

However, `grep` through loop did not return any value.

```
for(my $j=0; $j<$ln1; $j++){
    @S = grep /$AR1[$j]/, @AR3;
    $j++;
}
print @S;
```

The sample files are as follows:

```
@AR1
M1A3B6
M1AZ83

@AR3
>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG
>tr|M1AP92|Uncharacterized protein >>MQTLSRAQSQ
>tr|M1AZ83|Uncharacterized protein >>MASFTTLTSLFFFF
```

All suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The first code snippet is fine, that's how you would get elements that match the given regex.  The sample you show _does not_ have that -- none of the lines have the literal `M1ARK1` in them ... ?  So none of them will be matched by the regex, `grep` will return no elements, and `@S` is emtpy. The `for` loop is completely unclear -- what do you want to do with it and what are the variables?   Can you please clarify..

Comment: So OP edited the question and I am getting the grep content through loop. What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: @AbhiNickz: I am not returned with any output.

Comment: @Vinay What is this `$ln1` in for loop, I used it like this `for(my $j=0; $j<2; $j++){`

Comment: @Abhi:  $ln1  counts the number of lines. Code Snipper: while(my $line1=<FILE>) { push(@AR1,"$line1"); $ln1++;}

Comment: I also used this `for(my $j=0; $j<$#AR1; $j++){` and `for(my $j=0; $j<scalar(@AR1); $j++){` gives me correct result. `Before:$VAR1 = [
          '>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG'
        ];
After:$VAR1 = [
          '>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG'
        ];
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple significant problems in the structure of your posted code:

1. You're incrementing `$j` twice in each iteration (once with the `$j++` in the `for` statement itself, then another `$j++` in the body of the loop).  This will cause it to skip over every other element in `@AR1`.  Because it's so easy to make errors like this with C-style loops, it's generally better to use `for (@list)` instead of the C-style `for (;;)` when you're just iterating over a list of items.
2. You're assigning directly to `@S` on each iteration of the loop, which replaces any existing content with the new `grep` result.  This means that, at the end of the loop, `@S` contains only the results found in the final iteration instead of all the results found throughout the process.  You need to append to `@S` instead.
3. *ALWAYS* `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Yes, it can be a minor hassle to get used to them and satisfying their demands, but they are your best friends when it comes time for debugging.

Here's how I would do what your posted code appears to intend:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @ar1 = qw( M1A3B6 M1AZ83 );
my @ar3 = (
  '>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG',
  '>tr|M1AP92|Uncharacterized protein >>MQTLSRAQSQ',
  '>tr|M1AZ83|Uncharacterized protein >>MASFTTLTSLFFFF'
);

my @s;
for my $key (@ar1) {
  push @s, (grep /$key/, @ar3);
} 

say for @s;
```

And the resulting output:

```
>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG
>tr|M1AZ83|Uncharacterized protein >>MASFTTLTSLFFFF
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dave Sherohman, but I wanted to highlight a more concise syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @ar1 = qw( M1A3B6 M1AZ83 );
my @ar3 = (
  '>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG',
  '>tr|M1AP92|Uncharacterized protein >>MQTLSRAQSQ',
  '>tr|M1AZ83|Uncharacterized protein >>MASFTTLTSLFFFF'
);

my @s = map {my $key = $_;grep /$key/, @ar3} @ar1;

say for @s;
```

This uses the fact that the block part of map is evaluated in list context and may produce zero, one, or more elements in the returned value. This combine very nicely with grep when we want to concatenate all the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below as mentioned, Join the array using `|` then grep it.

```
my @ar1 = qw(M1A3B6 M1AZ83);
my @ar3 = (
  '>tr|M1A3B6|Uncharacterized protein >>MFNLHLLAVG',
  '>tr|M1AP92|Uncharacterized protein >>MQTLSRAQSQ',
  '>tr|M1AZ83|Uncharacterized protein >>MASFTTLTSLFFFF'
);

my $pattern = join("|",@ar1);
my @data = grep{ /$pattern/ } @ar3;
print "@data\n";
```